# What can be deduced about $x$ in the following statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

$$P(x) \equiv 
(x \neq 1 \land (\forall y, z \in \mathbb{N}): (x = yz \rightarrow (y = 1 \lor y = x))),  \forall x \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Question statement: If $P(x)$ is true, what can be said about $x$?

In this case, $\mathbb{N}$ includes the number $0$, which means if $P(x)$ is true then $x$ must be prime or equal to $0$? Or is there any other significant property of $x$ that I am missing out from the statement? Thank you!

Comment: If $x=0$ then $P(x)$ is not true; consider $y=2$ and $z=0$.

Comment: Also, what is the origin of this question?

Comment: @Servaes Thanks, I have edited the question, so x can only be prime right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  $P(x)$  holds, then $x$ is a prime number, but $x \neq 0$ by the counterexample you just mentioned. Just a comment on the syntax of the expression you've written; I would avoid using $=$ after $P(x)$ to denote "stands for", since the equality symbol has already a well-defined meaning when interpreted as standard equality of natural numbers. Instead, you can use the symbol $\equiv$.

Comment: If x = $0$, y =$2$, z = $0$, $0$ = ($2$)($0$), then y is not equal to 1 and y is not equal to x, wouldn't that make P(x) false? (question assumes natural numbers include $0$), so x cannot be $0$ right?