# Evaluating logic statement with quantifier

Tags: logic, solution-verification, quantifiers

P(x)= ( ≠ 1 ∧ ∀,  ∈ ℕ ( =  → ( = 1 ∨  = ))) , ∀ ∈ ℕ.

What can I say about x if P(x) is true for this statement other than x can be expressed as a product of 1 and its own.

Comment: Already [asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825654/what-can-be-deduced-about-x-in-the-following-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the predicate $P(x)$ states that $x$ is prime, since a prime $x$ is only divisible by $1$ or itself (if you consider as underlying set the natural numbers).

Comment: but x can be 4 right(composite number),while y can still be 1 or 4 in this case.